# How to convert two different array values into string in angularJS or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Given these two arrays:

```
$scope.city= [{id :'NewYork' } , {id : 'Chicago'}];
$scope.color = [{id : 'blue' } , {id : 'Green'}];
```

I need only the values of both arrays like this:

```
$scope.string = 'NewYork_Chicago_blue_Green';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using forEach:

```
    $scope.constructString = function(arr){
        arr.forEach(function(item){
        if($scope.string && $scope.string.length>0)
            $scope.string += '_';
        $scope.string +=  item.id;
    });

    $scope.constructString($scope.city);
    $scope.constructString($scope.color);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Array#map` to convert each array to an array of strings, then `Array#concat` them, and `Array#join` with underscore:

```js
var city = [ {id :'NewYork' } , {id : 'Chicago'}];
var color = [{id : 'blue' } , {id : 'Green'}];

function getId(o) {
  return o.id;
}

var result = city.map(getId).concat(color.map(getId)).join('_');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing the job could be;

```js
var city = [{id : 'NewYork'}, {id : 'Chicago'}],
   color = [{id : 'blue'}, {id : 'Green'}];
  result = city.concat(color)
               .reduce((p,c,i) => i-1 ? p    + "_" + c.id
                                      : p.id + "_" + c.id);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try these steps :**

- Array [**concat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method - used to merge two or more arrays.
- Array [**join()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method - joins all elements of an array into a string.

**Working demo :**

```js
var city= [ {id :'NewYork' } , {id : 'Chicago'}];

var color = [{id : 'blue' } , {id : 'Green'}];

var cityColor = city.concat(color);

var arr = [];

for (var i in cityColor) {
  arr.push(cityColor[i].id);
}

var str = arr.join('_');

console.log(str);
```